# Get specific value BeautifulSoup (parsing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract information from a website.

Using Python (**BeautifulSoup**)

I want to extract the following data (*just the figures*)

**EPS (Basic)**

from: *https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/income/quarter*
[image: EPS]

From the *xml*:

[image]

I'm built the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ur
import request 

url_is = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/income/quarter'


read_data = ur.urlopen(url_is).read()
soup_is=BeautifulSoup(read_data, 'lxml')
cells = soup_is.findAll('tr', {'class': 'mainRow'} )
for cell in cells:
  print(cell.text)
```

But I'm not to extract the figures for **EPS (Basic)**

[image: EPS]

Is there a way to extract just the data and sorted by column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following `css` selector which check td tag contains `EPS (Basic)` text .

```
import urllib.request as ur

url_is = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/income/quarter'
read_data = ur.urlopen(url_is).read()
soup_is=BeautifulSoup(read_data, 'lxml')
row = soup_is.select_one('tr.mainRow>td.rowTitle:contains("EPS (Basic)")')
print([cell.text for cell in row.parent.select('td') if cell.text!=''])
```

**Output**:

```
[' EPS (Basic)', '2.47', '2.20', '3.05', '5.04', '2.58']
```

---

To print in DF

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ur

url_is = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/income/quarter'
read_data = ur.urlopen(url_is).read()
soup_is=BeautifulSoup(read_data, 'lxml')
row = soup_is.select_one('tr.mainRow>td.rowTitle:contains("EPS (Basic)")')
data=[cell.text for cell in row.parent.select('td') if cell.text!='']
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.T)
```

**Output**:

```
              0     1     2     3     4     5
0   EPS (Basic)  2.47  2.20  3.05  5.04  2.58
```